# Node Express specific timeout value per route

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I'm developing a Node v4.2.4 application using Express v4.13.4. Now I would like to increase the timeout time for a specific upload route.

From what I've read and experienced:

- [the default Node server timeout is 2 minutes](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout)
- [a Node socket has no timeout by default](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback)
- [there's middleware from Express to handle timeouts](https://github.com/expressjs/timeout)

However, I'm lost when trying to implement the [connect-timeout](https://github.com/expressjs/timeout) middleware for the upload route.

**Application setup**

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: false }));
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use('/uploads', uploadRoutes);
app.use(errorHandler);

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.code && err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') {
    if (!res.headersSent) {
      res
        .status(408)
        .send({
          success: true,
          message: 'Timeout error'
        });
    }
  }

  next(err);
}

const server = app.listen(config.port);
```

**Upload route definition**

```
router.route('/:uploadId/upload-files')
  .post(timeout('3m'),
    require('./actions/upload-files').prepareHandler,
    require('./actions/upload-files').uploadHandler(),
    require('./actions/upload-files').responseHandler);
```

However, when uploading the files I do see the error from `express-timeout` after 3 minutes ONLY in the command line's console. The request is still in progress and no status code of 408 is returned.

After 4 minutes I finally see the 408 status and 'Timeout error' as part of the response object.

For requests to other routes I get the `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error after  4 minutes.

If I log the value for `server.timeout`, the value is `120000` (2 minutes).

**My questions**

- where can the 4 minutes possible come from? Is it because there's a preceding OPTIONS request maybe?
- what's the difference between server & socket timeouts and how to set them properly for a specific route?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've solved it using the following route configuration:

```
'use strict';

const ms = require('ms');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/upload-files')
  .post(
    setConnectionTimeout('12h'),
    require('./actions/upload-files').responseHandler
  );

function setConnectionTimeout(time) {
  var delay = typeof time === 'string'
    ? ms(time)
    : Number(time || 5000);

  return function (req, res, next) {
    res.connection.setTimeout(delay);
    next();
  }
}

exports.router = router;
```

Where the key logic is the following middleware:

```
  function (req, res, next) {
    res.connection.setTimeout(delay);
    next();
  }
```

I hope this reference will come in handy for others.

Comment: I think that `.connection.setTimeout()` exists on the request (req) not the response (res)

Answer (score 7):

Easy way to increase timeout on a route:

```
app.post('/some_route', (req, res) => {
   req.setTimeout(60 * 1000); //use req. this sets timeout to 60 seconds
});
```

**OR**

If you wanted to increase the timeout on the server for all routes, you can edit your app.js:

```
var serverApp = app.listen();
serverApp.setTimeout(60 * 1000); //use sets timeout to 60 seconds
```

Obviously, use the server setting sparingly. You don't want to tie up your server with long requests, so most of the time using the route specific timeouts is better architecture..