# Node server, socket, request and response timeouts

Tags: node.js, express

**Problem**

Node's default configuration timeouts requests after 2 minutes. I would like to change the request timeouts to:

- 1 minute for 'normal' requests
- 5 minutes for requests that serve static files (big assets in this case)
- 8 hours for uploads (couple of thousand pictures per request)

**Research**

Reading through [Node's documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-argon/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback), I've discovered that there are numerous ways of defining timeouts.

1. [server.setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-argon/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback)
2. [socket.setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-argon/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback)
3. [request.setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-argon/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback)
4. [response.setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-argon/api/http.html#http_response_settimeout_msecs_callback)

I'm using Express which also provides [middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/timeout) to define timeout's for (specific) routes. I've tried that, [without success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882237/node-express-specific-timeout-value-per-route).

**Question**

I'm confused about how to properly configure the timeout limit globally and per route. Should I configure all of the above timeouts? How is setting the server's timeout different to setting the socket's or request's timeout?

Comment: didnt this example help https://github.com/expressjs/timeout#connect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I saw on [your other question concerning the usage of the timeout middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882237/node-express-specific-timeout-value-per-route), you are using it somehow differently.

See documentation of [timeout-connect middleware.](https://github.com/expressjs/timeout#timeouttime-options)

Add your errorHandler-function as an EventListener to the request, as it is an EventEmitter and the middleware causes it to emit the `timeout`-event:

```
req.on("timeout", function (evt) {
    if (req.timedout) {
      if (!res.headersSent) {
        res
          .status(408)
          .send({
            success: true,
            message: 'Timeout error'
        });
      }
    }
});
```

This is called outside of the middleware stack, causing the function call to `next(err)` to be invalid. Also, you have to keep in mind, that if the timeout happens while the request is hanging server-side, you have to prevent your server code from further processing this request (because headers are already sent and its underlying connection will no longer be available).

Comment: Thanks for answering! How can I prevent other middleware functiona from processing this request, if using 'next()' is invalid here?

Comment: As Md. Nazmul Hossain Bilash's answer states, you can use another middleware layer between handlers that process on the request to check for `req.timedout`. Another way would be to override (monkey-patch) express' call to the `next` function and just prevent it if `req.timedout` is `true`.

Comment: Just to clarify again, call to `next()` is invalid here because this function is not a middleware or request handler! It is an event handler and will act outside of your request processing.

Answer (score 3):

## Summary

- nodejs timeout API are all inactivity timeout
- expressjs/timeout package is response hard timeout

## nodejs timeout API

**server.timeout**

- inactivity/idle timeout
- equal to socket timeout
- default 2min

**server.setTimeout**

- inactivity/idle timeout
- equal to socket timeout
- default 2min
- have callback

**socket.setTimeout**

- inactivity/idle timeout
- callback responsible to end(), destroy() socket
- default no timeout

**response.setTimeout**

- socket.setTimeout front end

**request.setTimeout**

- socket.setTimeout front end

## expressjs/timeout package

- response hard-timeout (vs inactivity)
- have callback

## Conclusion

- max. time allowed for an action(request+response), express/timeout package is needed.

  > This is properly what you need, but the callback need to end the request/response. As the timeout only trigger the callback, it does not change the state or interfere with the connection. It is the callback job.
- idle timeout, set nodejs api request/response timeout

  > I don't recommend touching these, as it is not necessary in most cases. Unless you want to allow a connection to idle(no traffic) over 2min.

Comment: Can you elaborate your conclusion about the max. time allowed for an action? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Voles By "Max. time allowed", an action(file transfer, or a db query) is given a certain time slot, let say 10min, then after 10min, the action, if not yet completed, will be terminated.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a Connect Middleware for Timeout support. You can try this middleware.

```
var timeout = express.timeout // express v3 and below
var timeout = require('connect-timeout'); //express v4

app.use(timeout(120000)); // should be changed with your desire time
app.use(haltOnTimedout);

function haltOnTimedout(req, res, next){
  if (!req.timedout) next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about "How is setting the server's timeout different to setting the socket's or request's timeout?"?