# How to extend the response timeout default time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, express, blocking

I'm having a little problem with thread blocking algorithms.

I have a route that generates a zip with huge size files.

The flow works like this:
GetUrls > ObtainHugeSizeBuffer > GenerateZIP > UploadZIPToCloud

I cannot modify the timeout response default time of 2 minutes with the `express-timeout` module. I've also been trying to break the loopholes in the `.nextTick()` function.

I've even tried to look over queueing but I don't think that applies in this situation.

Do you guys have any idea how to expand the response time? - I strictly need to for one route only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// start the server
const server = app.listen(8080);

// increase the timeout to 4 minutes
server.timeout = 240000;
```

This is the easiest way to extend server timeout, but it affects everything, not just one method.

In your case (you wan't it only for on specific route):

```
'use strict';

const ms = require('ms');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/upload-files')
  .post(
    setConnectionTimeout('12h'),
    require('./actions/upload-files').responseHandler
  );

function setConnectionTimeout(time) {
  var delay = typeof time === 'string'
    ? ms(time)
    : Number(time || 5000);

  return function (req, res, next) {
    res.connection.setTimeout(delay);
    next();
  }
}

exports.router = router;
```

Not my code, found it in this thead: [Node Express specific timeout value per route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882237/node-express-specific-timeout-value-per-route)

You need to google better :)

Comment: I strictly need it for one route only.

Comment: Edited answer, so this should help you

Comment: Okay, thanks I'll give it a try. Buy why timeout-express didn't worked in this case, that's strange...

Comment: I've used this solution [LINK](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/timeout.html)

Comment: Well your answer worked as a charm. Thanks a lot! It seems that I really need to develop even more my searching skills, thanks again!